# difference between npm ws and browser WebSocket Object

Tags: node.js, html, websocket, npm

I ham trying to attempt to use 'ws' from npm as WebSocket Object from browser?.

What is the difference between these two?. Does all the functions that works with WebSocket object available in 'ws' too?

Comment: Yes, but you'd typically use the `ws` package as the server, and not the client (though you can).

Comment: if i want to use as a client then shall i use npm install websocket as a client? is it official?

Comment: It's the same package. The client and server are just exposed on different objects.